# Redirect to one page in all Clients (Each client is a SessionScoped ManagedBean)

Tags: java, html, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a page with multiple users (Client 1, Client 2, ...) and I want to press the button "Salir de reunion" (Button 1) redirect me to a home page (http://localhost:8080/FasMe/faces / Public / Inicio.xhtml) on all clients.

Each client is a SessionScoped ManagedBean.

[image]

I only get redirected to the homepage (/Public/Inicio.xhtml) in the user (client) that press the button.
I want to do the redirect on all clients (browsers). How I can do?

**ReunionActiva.xhtml**

```
    <h:panelGrid id="reunionPanel" columns="2" >
            <h:commandButton value="Salir de Reunion" styleClass="btn" action="#{reunionBean.salirReunion}"  ></h:commandButton>                
    </h:panelGrid>
```

The business logic of my button "exit meeting" is:

**ReunionManagedBean.java** @ManagedBean(name="usuarioBean")

```
public String salirReunion(){

    Cuenta ctaCoordinador=participanteF.getCuentaReunion(reu, reuF.getCoordinadorReunion(reu.getIdReunion()));
    Cuenta ctaParticipante=ctaF.getCuentaByUsuario(usuarioActualBean.getCurrent(), ctaCoordinador.getServidorTareas());

    // If user is ADMIN then I want to delete all user of meeting and close de Meeting
    if(ctaCoordinador.getId().equals(ctaParticipante.getId())){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        reu.setFechaFin(cal.getTime());
        reu.setEstado("Cerrada"); // It´s meaning setStatus CLOSE
        reuF.modificacionReunion(reu);

        List<CuentaHasReunion> p=participanteF.getAllParticipantes(reu);
        for (Object element : p) {
            CuentaHasReunion part= (CuentaHasReunion) element;
            participanteF.bajaParticipante(part); //Here I delete all user from meeting
            // Here is where I need to do the redirect to all Clients (Client1 , Client2)
         }
        ReunionSingleton.eliminarReunionActiva(reu);
    }
    // If user isn't ADMIN then I only delete user who click the button "salir reunion"
    else{
        participanteF.bajaParticipante(participanteF.getParticipante(ctaParticipante, reu));

    }

    return "/Public/Reunion.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Comment: In plain JSF2/Ajax, periodically invoke a component/ajax call that checks that the meeting is still active and, when it is not, causes the redirect. In Primefaces there is a component that implements this and presents as "sending messages from the server to the browsers", but I can't remember its name and have not used it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ICEfaces Push](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/ajax-push.jsf) (seem to have been the first kids on the block with this) and  [PrimeFaces Push](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf). Normally the web is request based, so each client needs to ask for the refresh. I believe these allow the client to ask periodically via ajax if there is anything interesting on the server with little request packets. If the server says yes, the client then says update me. In any case, I think this is what you might be looking for.

If you need something more synchronous you might need to implement something using network sockets or RMI, maybe via via an applet.